# How to best store time series data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I regularly have to conduct chemical experiments which result in a huge set of time serie data. For example, 100 lists with measured concentration of fluids and for each measurement an assigned timestamp in microseconds.

I would like to track and model each experiment and assign to it multiple lists with (measurement, timestamp) pairs. The measurement lists do not have to be of equal length and can greatly vary. For example, one measurement list could be of length 100, the next one 4000, always depending on the conducted experiment. When being at the university lab, I also take notes for different timestamps, which I would also like to track for the timestamps in the DB (tagged timestamps).

Later on, the full analysis text of the experiment should also be stored.

Is Elasticsearch capable of storing such time series data or measurement lists? Because this is not mostly text but rather numbers I'm a bit restraint.

Even though I have searched through the net for a while, I could not find a proper way to set up measurement lists as explained yet.

Any help, ideas and maybe helpful links are highly appreciated!

Comment: You have a very simple, fixed schema (experimentID, timestamp, value). That would work well with a regular SQL database. Any reasons you can't use one of those?

Comment: Reason is that I want to perform fast searches on the analysis text and assigned refernce papers of each experiment. A use case for example, search in the analysis text for some keyword and then get me all assigned measurement lists and do some analysis on the measured data.

Comment: I think, Elasticsearch is suitable for my setup, but my real struggle really is how I would model such measurement lists in Elasticsearch.

Comment: I know that this is your struggle, you wrote your question about it. I'm not convinced that Elastic is the right tool for what you're doing. Regular SQL databases can do fast searches on text, that's not an issue at all. They can also do keyword lists. How many records with text/keywords are we talking about? A few thousand? A few hundred thousand?